# How to merge 2 arrays with objects in one?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

1. `[{name:'test', lastname: 'test', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'f'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'}]`
2. `[{name:'test21', lastname: 'test21', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'f'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'},{name:'test22', lastname: 'test22', gender:'m'}]`

How to merge these in one array with unique objects (for unique check 'name')?

Comment: I need only unique objects in new array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of `filter` and `find` will work

```
var a = [{name:'test', lastname: 'test', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'f'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'}];

var b = [{name:'test21', lastname: 'test21', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'f'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'},{name:'test22', lastname: 'test22', gender:'m'}];

var c = a.filter(a => b.find(b => b.name === a.name) === undefined).concat(b);

console.table(c);
```

[image]

---

You could also make a generic `uniqueByKey` function

```
var uniqueByKey = (key, xs)=>
  xs.reduce((ys,x)=>
    ys.find(y=> y[key] === x[key]) === undefined
      ? ys.concat([x])
      : ys,
    []);

var a = [{name:'test', lastname: 'test', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'f'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'}];

var b = [{name:'test21', lastname: 'test21', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'f'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'},{name:'test22', lastname: 'test22', gender:'m'}];

var c = uniqueByKey('name', a.concat(b));

console.table(c);
```

[image]

---

If you're dealing with particularly large datasets, using a `Set` cache instead of `Array.prototype.find` might be better.

```
var uniqueByKey = (key, xs)=>
  xs.reduce(([set, ys], x)=>
    set.has(x[key])
      ? [set, ys]
      : [set.add(x[key]), ys.concat([x])]
    , [new Set, []]
  ) [1];

var a = [{name:'test', lastname: 'test', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'f'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'}];

var b = [{name:'test21', lastname: 'test21', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'f'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'},{name:'test22', lastname: 'test22', gender:'m'}];

var c = uniqueByKey('name', a.concat(b));

console.table(c);
```

[image]

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at this question? I tried your fix here, but didn't work in my case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953925/how-to-merge-2-arrays-with-similar-objects

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr1 = [{name:'test', lastname: 'test', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'f'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'}]
var arr2 = [{name:'test', lastname: 'test', gender:'f'},{name:'test21', lastname: 'test21', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'f'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'},{name:'test22', lastname: 'test22', gender:'m'}]

var newArray =arr1.concat(arr2);
var unique = {};
var result = [];


newArray.forEach(function (elem) {
  if (!unique[elem.name]) {
    result.push(elem);
    unique[elem.name] = true;
  }
});
console.log(result);
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to check duplicate elements the fastest method is to add all elements to an object with the name that you want as key, because accessing the keys is very fast:

```
var unified = {},
    unifiedArray = [],
    first = [{name:'test', lastname: 'test', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'f'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'}],
    second = [{name:'test21', lastname: 'test21', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'f'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'},{name:'test22', lastname: 'test22', gender:'m'}],
    addToUnified = function(obj) {
        if (unified[obj.name]) {
            alert('duplicate detected!\n' + JSON.stringify(obj) + '\n' + ' has same name as\n'  + JSON.stringify(unified[obj.name]));
        } else {
            unifiedArray.push(obj);
            unified[obj.name] = obj;
        }
    }
first.forEach(addToUnified);
second.forEach(addToUnified);
```

If you just want to get a report you don't need the `unifiedArray`. If you don't need the report just eliminate the `alert`

Answer (score 0):

For a new array, you could use an object as hash table for lookup.

```js
var array1 = [{ name: 'test', lastname: 'test', gender: 'f' }, { name: 'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender: 'f' }, { name: 'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender: 'm' }],
    array2 = [{ name: 'test21', lastname: 'test21', gender: 'f' }, { name: 'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender: 'f' }, { name: 'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender: 'm' }, { name: 'test22', lastname: 'test22', gender: 'm' }],
    result = function (a1, a2) {
        function merge(a) {
            this[a.name] = this[a.name] || r.push(a);
        }

        var t = Object.create(null),
            r = [];
        a1.forEach(merge, t);
        a2.forEach(merge, t);
        return r;
    }(array1, array2);

console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
var array1 = [{ name: 'test', lastname: 'test', gender: 'f' }, { name: 'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender: 'f' }, { name: 'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender: 'm' }],
    array2 = [{ name: 'test21', lastname: 'test21', gender: 'f' }, { name: 'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender: 'f' }, { name: 'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender: 'm' }, { name: 'test22', lastname: 'test22', gender: 'm' }],
    result = function (a1, a2) {
        var t = Object.create(null),
            r = [],
            m = a => t[a.name] = t[a.name] || r.push(a);
        a1.forEach(m);
        a2.forEach(m);
        return r;
    }(array1, array2);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: How about if names are same but last names differ like in case Adnan Blackball and Adnan Goldenhorn.

Comment: i don't care, because the question us not clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if you have an Object method like `Object.prototype.compare()`. Lets make it.

```
Object.prototype.compare = function(o){
  var ok = Object.keys(this);
  return typeof o === "object" && ok.length === Object.keys(o).length ? ok.every(k => this[k] === o[k]) : false;
};
```

`Object.prototype.compare()` compares two objects for a perfect match of all properties and their values. So unlike the accepted answer we are not comparing a single property but all of them. Now it's a simple reducing task. Let's see

```js
Object.prototype.compare = function(o){
  var ok = Object.keys(this);
  return typeof o === "object" && ok.length === Object.keys(o).length ? ok.every(k => this[k] === o[k]) : false;
};

var arr1 = [{name:'test', lastname: 'test', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'f'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'}],
    arr2 = [{name:'test21', lastname: 'test21', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'f'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'},{name:'test22', lastname: 'test22', gender:'m'}],
  united = arr1.reduce((p,c) => p.find(f => f.compare(c)) ? p : p.concat(c),arr2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(united));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [{name:'test', lastname: 'test', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'f'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'}];

var b = [{name:'test21', lastname: 'test21', gender:'f'},{name:'test1', lastname: 'test1', gender:'f'},{name:'test2', lastname: 'test2', gender:'m'},{name:'test22', lastname: 'test22', gender:'m'}];

var c = a.filter(a => b.find(b => b.name === a.name) === undefined).concat(b);

console.table(c);
```

Comment: You should add some text explaining what it is you're doing.