# How to merge 2 arrays with similar objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

IE: I have 2 arrays one with prices, one with names.

The one with prices is longer, and I only want the final array to be the size of the smaller array with only names.

Objects in the prices array:

```
{
  currency: 'BTC',
  price: '6500'
},
{
  currency: 'NEM',
  price: '1'
},
```

Objects in the name array:

```
{
  currency: 'BTC',
  name: 'Bitcoin'
}
```

The final array should only contain objects that exist in the `name` array, but also have the `price` key from the `prices` array.

```
{
  currency: 'BTC',
  name: 'Bitcoin',
  price: '6500'
}
```

I had accomplished this using an NPM package, however the package is old and there is a bug when compiling:
[Error while running NPM run build (ERROR in index_bundle.js from UglifyJs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953226/error-while-running-npm-run-build-error-in-index-bundle-js-from-uglifyjs)

I also found this answer here: [How to merge 2 arrays with objects in one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562375/how-to-merge-2-arrays-with-objects-in-one) However none of the answers worked. Neither was the array filtered by the smaller array, but the keys were not combined either.

Comment: How about `Object.assign({}, object1, object2)`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is using the function `map` to generate a new array with the desired output.

This approach uses the function `find` to retrieve the specific object price related to an object name `name.currency === price.currency`.

```js
let prices = [{  currency: 'BTC',  price: '6500'},{  currency: 'BSS',  price: '850'},{  currency: 'USD',  price: '905'}],
    names = [{  currency: 'BTC',  name: 'Bitcoin'},{  currency: 'BSS',  name: 'Bolivar'}],
    result = names.map(n => Object.assign({}, n, prices.find(p => p.currency === n.currency)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Ah thanks! I keep trying to filter the prices array, this is much more straight forward and easier :)

Comment: @LeonGaban you're welcome `(:`